# Changing Wagtail Userbar Icon

Tags: python, django, wagtail

How to change Wagtail Userbar Icon?
I want to make it more personalize but I don't know how since I am new in web development.

[Wagtail Userbar Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edpqT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also modify wagtail's icon font. Then you don't have to touch any of the code.

The font file is at
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/8e0b2f6d1da6c18ad1aaaa8366f02e6c8cf76027/wagtail/admin/static_src/wagtailadmin/fonts/wagtail-icomoon.json

I used a slightly modified version of the instructions at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/wiki/Adding-new-icon

- go to https://icomoon.io/app/
- hamburger menu -> Manage project -> Import project
- open the font
- Rename 'Untitled Project 1' to 'Wagtail'
- click 'Load'
- switch to the edit tool and select the bird icon (there are two of them. The one you want will be named uni56)
- Click replace and choose an svg to replace it with. (I just downloaded one from the icomoon library)
- From the hamburger menu next to Wagtail, 'select all', then 'Generate font'
- Unpack the zip file, and copy the contents of the 'fonts' folder to static/wagtailadmin/fonts/ in any of your apps

as long as your app comes before wagtail.admin in INSTALLED_APPS it will use your modified font instead
[modified icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tfRI.png)

Comment: I believe the instructions were moved to https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/wiki/Adding-new-icons, is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the accepted answer stopped working for me in the latest version of Wagtail. Rather than figure out why, I found a simpler solution:

Create `wagtailadmin/userbar/base.html`:

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/userbar/base.html" %}

{% load wagtailadmin_tags i18n %}

{% block branding_logo %}
  <div style="display: none">
    <svg>
        <defs>
          <!-- Replace 'wagtail.svg' with whatever you want from the icons directory, e.g. 'cogs.svg' -->
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/cogs.svg" %}
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/folder-open-inverse.svg" %}
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/edit.svg" %}
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/plus.svg" %}
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/tick.svg" %}
          {% include "wagtailadmin/icons/cross.svg" %}
        </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- Update the icon name -->
  {% icon name="cogs" class_name="wagtail-userbar-icon" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can see the toolbar but not the new icon.

Comment: @GeoMeteoMe Sounds like your template isn’t overriding the default. I’m not sure why but might be an avenue to explore.

Comment: It might me version related. My user/base.html template has svg tag at the bottom where use href has to be updated to <use href="#icon-edit"></use>

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert a FontAwesome icon instead, just create the HTML page [wagtailadmin/userbar/base.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/8e0b2f6d1da6c18ad1aaaa8366f02e6c8cf76027/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/userbar/base.html) in one of your Django app templates folders.  This will override the html provided by Wagtail.

Then in the template delete the call to the **wagtail-icon** CSS class, which inserts the Wagtail logo, and insert your icon, in this case a fontawesome pencil icon ...

```
    <div class="wagtail-userbar-trigger" data-wagtail-userbar-trigger>
        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="wagtail-userbar-help-text">
        {% trans 'My personal admin interface' %}
        </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

[Here is how to adjust size etc](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/) of the Fontawesome image, in this case **fa-2x** doubles the size of the pencil.

Wagtails built-in edit icon can be used by editing the **div class** like so ...

```
<div class="wagtail-userbar-trigger wagtail-icon wagtail-icon-edit" data-wagtail-userbar-trigger>
```

[image]

The FontAwesome method provides more options though.

**Note:** As mentioned this creates a maintainability issue, however IMO usability would be increased by this change, as most users do not understand what Wagtail CMS is, or what clicking a bird might symbolise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.